# Swift Eureka error inside library after installation

Tags: ios, swift, installation, eureka-forms

I just did install Eurika library from xmartslab
I already googled this problem, unfortunally found nothing

As usual added it to my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'    
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Eureka', '~> 1.5'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
end
```

After installation I got a bunch of errors:

[image]
What can cause this problem. Could it be any incompatibility with other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Xcode 7.2 or older. You will have to upgrade to Xcode 7.3 or change your Podfile to `pod 'Eureka', '~> 1.4.1'`

Comment: I am using Xcode 7.2. I'll update it today and will check

Comment: @ Mathias Claassen this exactly was the case. After updating my xcode  all the errors were gone. I accept you answer